# Oracle error message: DPY-4004: invalid number

Tags: python, oracle

I am creating a table in Oracle db with following lines in python script.

```
cur.execute('''BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MRCONSO'; 
               EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; 
               END;
            ''')

try:
    cur.execute('''
                CREATE TABLE MRCONSO (
                CUI char(8) NOT NULL,
                LAT char(3) NOT NULL,
                TS char(1) NOT NULL,
                LUI varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
                STT varchar2(3) NOT NULL,
                SUI varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
                ISPREF char(1) NOT NULL,
                AUI varchar2(9) NOT NULL,
                SAUI integer,
                SCUI varchar2(100),
                SDUI varchar2(100),
                SAB varchar2(40) NOT NULL,
                TTY varchar2(40) NOT NULL,
                CODE varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
                STR varchar2(3000) NOT NULL,
                SRL integer NOT NULL,
                SUPPRESS char(1) NOT NULL,
                CVF integer)
                PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 80
                '''
               )
    
    print("MRCONSO Table Created")
                
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ",str(e))
```

When I insert the data using csv file, I get following error.

```
Oracle error message: DPY-4004: invalid number
```

```
df_umls = pd.read_csv("../umls_files/umls-2023AA-metathesaurus-full/2023AA/META/MRCONSO.RRF", sep = '|', low_memory=False)
df_umls.columns=["CUI", "LAT", "TS", "LUI", "STT", "SUI", "ISPREF", "AUI","SAUI", "SCUI", "SDUI", "SAB", "TTY", "CODE", "STR", "SRL", "SUPPRESS", "CVF", "JUNK"]
df_umls = df_umls.drop(columns=['JUNK'])

df_umls['CVF'] = df_umls['CVF'].fillna(0) 
df_umls['CVF'] = df_umls['CVF'].astype("Int64") 

df_umls['SAUI'] = df_umls['SAUI'].fillna(0) 
df_umls['SAUI'] = df_umls['SAUI'].astype("Int64") 


try:
    if conn:
        print("Oracle version:", oracledb.version)
        print("Database version:", conn.version)
        #print("Client version:", oracledb.clientversion())
        print('Inserting data into table....')
        for i,row in tqdm(df_umls.iterrows(), total=df_umls.shape[0]):
            sql_conso = "insert into MRCONSO (CUI,LAT,TS,LUI,STT,SUI,ISPREF, AUI, SAUI, SCUI, SDUI, SAB, TTY, CODE, STR, SRL, SUPPRESS, CVF) values (:0,:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17)"
            cur.execute(sql_conso, tuple(row))
        # the connection is not autocommitted by default, so we must commit to save our changes
        conn.commit()
        print("Record inserted succesfully")
except DatabaseError as e:
    err, = e.args
    print("Oracle-Error-Code:", err.code)
    print("Oracle-Error-Message:", err.message)
finally:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

The dataframe datatype is:

```
CUI object
LAT object
TS object
LUI object
STT object
SUI object
ISPREF object
AUI object
SAUI Int64
SCUI object
SDUI object
SAB object
TTY object
CODE object
STR object
SRL int64
SUPPRESS object
CVF Int64
dtype: object
```

How should I modify the dataframe to insert the data into table successfully.

Comment: You need to figure out which column it's complaining about. Try removing dataframe columns one by one from the `INSERT` until the error goes away.

Comment: If you used the more efficient `executemany()` instead of the loop over `execute()`, the `batcherrors` option might help identify the cause, see https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#handling-data-errors

Comment: If you get DPY-3002 and have issues with Int64 you may need to recast it to a float:  something like `for idx, row in df.iterrows(): bnd.append((row[0].astype('float64'),))`

Comment: @ChristopherJones Actually the columns are of datatype Integer which are converted to float while loading the csv to dataframe.